# 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection in CF Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

when I try to access my application I received the following message.

*500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection*

I did the traceroute and from the 16th attempt the address stopped responding.

What can it be?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information such as what services your application uses? A variety of scenarios can cause this issue.

Comment: Hi Bill. I'm running a Rails app on server with 1 instances and 2gb memory.  The app allow execute uploads and downloads archives with 500mb size.

Answer (score 1):

are you still getting the error or now it is working?
Reading at it, it seems related with a temporary outage of Bluemix service, here the status page of Bluemix 
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status
On this page you can find also notices of temporary problems with related updates.
Anyway the traceroute output couldn't be a useful information, because very often most hosts don't respond to pinging because of security reasons.

Comment: Hi I see this problem, but my problem it occurred before.

Comment: OK, could you please check if it is still happening? If so, could you please report the commands you are using?